# executing python script no output

Tags: python, function, flask, subprocess, popen

I wrote a script and when I run it in the shell, it prints the values, output correct(sudo python /home/pi/map/apps/assistant/IFTTT.py):

```
def GetCalenderMessages():
    print("test")
    CalenderMessage = bus_service.receive_queue_message('calendar',   peek_lock=True)
    if CalenderMessage != None:
        message = str(CalenderMessage.body)
        queuemessage = message.split('|')[1]
        print(queuemessage)

        sys.stdout.write(queuemessage)
        saytts(queuemessage)
        CalenderMessage.delete()
```

I have an interface with an On switch and when I press On this script should be executed, which works, but I'm not getting the print output defined I the script above.

```
@app_bp.route("/on", methods=["POST"])
@opsoroapp.app_api
def on():
    print('test')
    cmd = "sudo python /home/pi/OnoSW/apps/assistant/IFTTT.py"
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline,''):
        print line
```

I tried different things with subprocess, like subprocess.check_output etc but it doesn't give the printed values back.

Thank You

Comment: Why are you doing this via Popen? Why can't you simply import the script and call the function?

Comment: your function should return a value instead using `print()`, `sys.stdout.write()`, etc and as @DanielRoseman said: import the module and call the function instead of running it as a separate process. 1- do you see the result of `print('test')`? 2- Do you see the result of `print >>sys.stderr, "stderr"`? 3- Do you need to provide a password to run `sudo python`? Why do you need `sudo` here?

Answer (score 0):

1) Instead of using pipes and `Popen`, just import the script and call `GetCalenderMessages`

2) Do you want it just printed to the console or outputted to the webapp user?

In case the second scenario is the case:

in your `route` function, you don't seem to `return` anything. Remember how flask routes work, what you return (on success) gets outputted to the user (in the form of a web page) so you'll need to store your result and then return it as a string OR add it to a HTML template and `render` that template instead.

[See more](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/templating/)

in case you want it printed to console, trying 1) could fix your problem

Comment: option 1 is not an option. In option 2 this time I returned the output but it doesn't do anything. I'm gonna show my problem: when I run in the shell this command 'sudo python IFTTT.py ill get: http://i.imgur.com/iqiNZRT.png   when I run it in the flask webserver ill get: http://i.imgur.com/HZzyXpI.png , dont look at the first error its because I use Python 2.7

Comment: Why are you using sudo - it is very rare that any application needs root priveleges.

Comment: when you do a 'sudo' in the terminal, Unix/Linux will prompt for a password. When you do a 'sudo' via pOpen - it will still expect a password - and wont run until you give that password. The questions that were asked are valid - why are you using `sudo` and why are you creating a separate process ? You claim you have to - but unless we understand why it will be tough to help you.